# Can't retrieve value inside struct from a different class (returns 0)

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, struct

I'm having a problem right now, I have two classes and I'm trying to access a variable defined in a struct from another class. If I try to access that certain variable from its default location, it returns just fine but if I try to access it from another class it returns as 0. I've tried debugging and it did nothing at all (didn't help much) so I don't know where the issue is at. I'm asking this question here as a last resort because I've searched all over the place for this particular issue and I couldn't come up with a conclusion.

**The struct, it's defined outside the CBasePlayer class:**

```
//Player table definition
typedef struct _PlayerInfo {
    char name[MAX_PLAYER_NAME];
    char playermodel[24];
    BYTE score;
    BYTE ping;
    UINT8 connected;
    UINT8 pactive;
    UINT8 pspawned;
    UINT8 pconnected;
    UINT8 pfakeclient;
    UINT8 pedicts;// Table - open with memOpen
    string pname;
    UINT8 puserid;
    string puserinfo;
    int pconnecttime;
    UINT8 plagcompensation;
    UINT8 pnext_messageinterval;
    int pnext_heartbeat;
    int plast_heartbeat;
    int pinternaluserid;
} PlayerInfo;
```

**I put this in the CPP file at the top of it (It's not inside any class):**

```
std::vector<_PlayerInfo> players;
```

**The function I'm calling from the class named CNetwork:**

```
int CBasePlayer::GetBeat( int playerid, int type ) { //1 for next, 2 for last
    setPointerForPlayerID(playerid);
    std::vector<_PlayerInfo>::iterator it = players.begin();
    _PlayerInfo player;
    int i = 0;
    int value = 0;
    while(it != players.end()) { //This is where player.plast_heartbeat and player.pnext_heartbeat become 0
        player = *(it++);
        if(playerid == player.pinternaluserid) {
            value = (type == LAST_BEAT) ? player.plast_heartbeat : player.pnext_heartbeat;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

*player.plast_heartbeat* and *player.pnext_heartbeat* are both 0 when being accessed from a different class but their values are just right in its own class (so even though they show as "0" when being accessed from another class, they do actually have a value).

**This is how I'm accessing them:**

```
void CNetwork::OnPreClientDisconnect( void ) { //Can't do int playerid here, once the heartbeat is gone all the info is lost on disconnect and it can't be parsed from the server
    CBasePlayer * pPlayer = new CBasePlayer;
    int lastbeat, nextbeat;
    for(int i=0; i<pPlayer->NumClients(); i++) {
        pPlayer->setPointerForPlayerID(i);
        nextbeat = pPlayer->GetBeat( i, NEXT_BEAT );
        lastbeat = pPlayer->GetBeat( i, LAST_BEAT );
        if(pPlayer->IsClientOnTable(i)) {
            if(pPlayer->LostBeat(lastbeat, nextbeat))
                OnClientDisconnect(i, REASON_DISCONNECT); //They lost the heartbeat, remove them from the table and disconnect them. If anything, they'll be readded to the table on the next queue.
        }
    }
    free(pPlayer);
}
```

I've had this issue countless times with classes as well and I had to resolve it by making all its variables static and then initializing them.
Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your help and I apologize for posting so much code. Knowing why values get "reset" like this will really help me since I've had this problem for a long time by now.

**Update, here's the video:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXKFjiStrKo&feature=youtu.be

**Here's the compilable example: [31/03/2014]**

http://www.iw-rp.com/files/compilable_example.zip

Comment: Regarding the "vanishing zeroes" issue, there's an error in code that you haven't shown. Post a compilable program that outputs things and demonstrates the issue (preferably try to make this as small as you can by leaving out irrelevant parts).

Comment: If you're setting the data in a similar way then you're probably working on a copy of the player info instead of the instance stored in the vector. `player = *(it++);` is making the copy.

Comment: Also you may be causing undefined behaviour by accessing uninitialized variables - if you create a `PlayerInfo` without initializing it then the variables will have garbage values.

Comment: Matt McNabb: PlayerInfo has values which are getting inserted when a player connects to the server. Captain Obvlious: That makes sense to me.

Comment: I still couldn't resolve this issue, the values seem to vanish. I would post a compilable version but I would require to post a lot of code just to have that done. I will post a video demonstrating what happens in a bit by the way.

Comment: You need to show the code that is inserting into the vector.  The simple explanation is the vector has holes (subscripts) with _PlayerInfo's that were never initialized.

Comment: Hey Brian, I posted a compilable example, you can find it at the bottom of the question under "here's the compilable example." Thanks. P.S: AddPlayerToTable does that, which is in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood std::vector<_PlayerInfo> players is a member of CBasePlayer, so each instance of this class has its own players vector. Everytime you create a new instance of this class:  CBasePlayer * pPlayer = new CBasePlayer; you create a new vector of players. I'm not sure how you want to share the vector across as instances of this class. As you said defining the vector as static would solve your problem. What you probably wanted to do is make std::vector<_PlayerInfo> players a member of the CNetwork class instead so you can access it from functions within like OnPreClientDisconnect().

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I solved this by setting the variables as static inside the struct and then initializing them in the CPP file like so:

**Struct:**

```
//Player table definition
typedef struct _PlayerInfo {
    char name[MAX_PLAYER_NAME];
    char playermodel[24];
    BYTE score;
    BYTE ping;
    UINT8 connected;
    UINT8 pactive;
    UINT8 pspawned;
    UINT8 pconnected;
    UINT8 pfakeclient;
    UINT8 pedicts;// Table - open with memOpen
    string pname;
    UINT8 puserid;
    string puserinfo;
    static int pconnecttime;
    UINT8 plagcompensation;
    UINT8 pnext_messageinterval;
    static int pnext_heartbeat;
    static int plast_heartbeat;
    static int pinternaluserid;
} PlayerInfo;
```

**Initialization:**

```
int _PlayerInfo::pconnecttime;
int _PlayerInfo::pnext_heartbeat;
int _PlayerInfo::plast_heartbeat;
int _PlayerInfo::pinternaluserid;
```

Now the variables don't get re-initialized anymore when being called from other classes.
I don't think it's a really neat solution, but it worked. Thank you all for your help.